# Adding If statement using python3

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.5, openpyxl

Using `openpyxl` I am working on creating a new excel workbook. I need to add `conditional` statements for some cells like,

For example:

```
=IF(C19="John","","X")
```

I am unable to find respective function from `openpyxl` module to add `conditions`. Is there any function which I can use from this `openpyxl` ?

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-formulae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily:

```
>>> from openpyxl import Workbook
>>> wb = Workbook()
>>> ws = wb.active
>>> # add a simple formula
>>> ws["A1"] = '=IF(C19="John","","X")'
>>> wb.save("formula.xlsx")
```

From the doc:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/usage.html